# Python, return IP address of list of urls

Tags: python

I am trying to automate a task with Python where a have a .txt file list of urls and converts it to a .txt file list of IP addresses. Domain.txt has an active url on each line, and IP.py is as follows:

```
import socket

urls = open('domain.txt', 'r')

for lines in urls:
    IP = socket.gethostbyname(lines)
print(IP)
```

I am running this script wrong by calling it with:

```
$ python3 IP.py domain.txt
```

What is proper syntax for this script?

The output error I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "IP.py", line 6, in <module>
    IP = socket.gethostbyname(lines)
socket.gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: try only `python3 IP.py`

Comment: What's the website's name?

Comment: edit your question to include all relevant info, don't "add" info in comments

Comment: I don't know about formatting but have you tried removing all spaces. I guess there must be a function for that. You never know how a file was originally formatted

Comment: @SethS.py what is it that you don't understand with the error? The DNS lookup for the argument passed in `socket.gethostbyname` failed.

Comment: There is new line char at the end of the line. strip that new-line char

Comment: domain.txt is a list of around 100 subdomains with a active subdomain on each line

Comment: I removed the extra lines, thank you for pointing that out. I also ran the script without the .txt file and am still getting an error

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that you are getting an error that looks something like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "StackOverflow.py", line 7, in <module>
    IP = socket.gethostbyname(lines)
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

In your case, the issue isn't the socket library but probably the way you are taking in your input. For example, try running this code and see what happens:

```
urls = open('lowes.txt', 'r')

links = []
for link in urls.readlines():
    links.append(link)

print(links)
```

Here is an example output:

```
['google.com\n', 'yahoo.com\n', 'facebook.com']
```

See that `\n` at the end? Whenever you throw that into the socket library, it crashes because there is no website called `"google.com\n"`.

It's an easy fix though, just make sure to strip out the newline using `line.strip()`.
Like this:

```
import socket

urls = open('lowes.txt', 'r')

for lines in urls:
    IP = socket.gethostbyname(lines.strip())
    print(IP)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one, it works fine as i added `lines.strip()` to tackle the newline after the urls like `google.com\n`

```
import socket

urls = open('domain.txt', 'r')

for lines in urls:
    IP = socket.gethostbyname(lines.strip())
print(IP)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import socket

urls = open('domain.txt', 'r')
lines = urls.readlines()  # read all the lines of txt
urls.close()

for index, line in enumerate(lines):  # iterate over each line
    lines[index] = socket.gethostbyname(line[:-1]) + '\n'  # replace each url line by ip

with open('domain.txt', 'w') as urls:
    urls.writelines(lines)  # save all the lines
```